# jquery remembering the link I clicked and returning to that point on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Basically I have a link at the bottom of a lot of content that when clicked scrolls the user to the top of the page and then fades in a modal box with additional content. This modal box has a link to close the box, what I would like to do when the close link is selected is scroll  back down to the link that was originally clicked. Can anyone advise me on how this might be achieved?

I have set up a fiddle but for some reason get an error when i try to run it http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/ExEJy/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ExEJy/26/

I just added a `lastScrollPosition` variable that is set every time your button is clicked and then read when the modal is closed.

---

I might be stealing your idea, so I just added a fading background.